# Serial communication confusion

Tags: serial

I'm trying to understand how to talk to ESP8266, but I'm very confused. I don't understand how to connect ESP8266 to serial, so I can send it commands from terminal, as far as I understood I need special hardware to do this which I don't have.

I have raspberry Pi and want to use it's GPIO pins to send the 'AT+GMR' command and read the response from the ESP8266.

I want to do this at low level, but I don't know what to look for, because I don't understand the process.

If I set one GPIO as output and connect it to ESP8266 RX and other GPIO as input and connect it to ESP8266 TX, what's next? I would simply write my command byte by byte and new line at the end and ESP8266 should give out singnal from TX to GPIO input? There is no 'protocol' in between or some kind of timing? Thanks

Comment: Why are you not using the serial pins?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams What would be the benefit?

Comment: Serial is an asynchronous (i.e. without clock) protocol, where the timing between transitions is important. You can't simply write a byte to a single pin - it doesn't fit.

Comment: Other than the fact that you can use the serial peripheral on the RPi's SoC instead of bitbanging out serial?

Comment: If you are a beginner I recommend getting a NodeMCU instead of bare-ESP modules. NodeMCU is still dirty cheap but has everything needed to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is a protocol, described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_serial_communication):

[image]

Technically, it should be possible to program such protocol manually, using GPIO pins, but you'll inevitably get issues at higher baud rates, as your program will fail to respect the timing properly.

It's much better to use UART hardware which is available on all the RPi boards. [Locate](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals) Tx and Rx pins on your board, [disable](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-operating-systems/raspbian/io-pins-raspbian/uart-pins) linux login console on UART device and connect your ESP8266 to these pins (Rx of ESP8266 to Tx of RPi and vice versa). Then you'll be able to simply write your AT strings to `/dev/ttyAMA0` file and read responses from it.

Comment: Thank you! I connected the ESP8266 to RX/TX, but when I connect to /dev/ttyAMA0 nothing happens and I can't type. I tried to start the ESP8266, but I can see it blink once when it powers up, but no data sent/received, I'm guessing it's an software issue.

Comment: Did you check which baud rate ESP8266 expects and configured /dev/ttyAMA0 to that baud rate?

Comment: I tried 9600, 115200, 57600 and 76800, but still the issue persists

Comment: 1. Why did you have to try, don't you know which one it is? Did this device come with documentation of some kind? 2. How do you "connect" to the serial device exactly? Do you use a tool like `putty`, `minicom` or `screen`, or do you open it programmatically? Add the command line or the source code to your question.

Comment: Because there are many versions of this module and depending on the version the baud rate is different, that's why I decided to try the ones listen by other users. I also ran 'raspi-config' and disabled login shell via serial and set enable_uart=1 in /boot/config.txt, but nothing changed. I I'm trying to connect using screen command 'screen /dev/ttyAMA0 baud_rate'.

Comment: What you did looks good to me. Since you mention `enable_uart=1` may I ask if you happen to have RPi 3? They have changed the serial name from `/dev/ttyAMA0` to `/dev/ttyS0` in the latest boards.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the tip, but still the same issue. I'm starting to think maybe the module is faulty or my raspberry pins are burned or something. I described my steps here in detail: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/259141/cant-connect-esp8266-to-raspberry-serial if you could take a look at it, I would greatly appreciate it!