# Can't connect ESP8266 to Raspberry serial

Tags: serial, esp8266

I have been trying to get ESP8266 WIFI module (ESP-12E) to connect to Raspberry PI 3 serial port, but I've tried everything I could think of, but still can't get it to connect.

**Connection**

I have connected it directly to Raspberry Pi 3 the following way:
[image]

I followed this datasheet: http://www.kloppenborg.net/images/blog/esp8266/esp8266-esp12e-specs.pdf

Which states:

```
  MODE        GPIO15     GPIO0     GPIO2

  UART        Low        Low       High
  Flash Boot  Low        High      High
```

So far so good, but when I apply the power, nothing happens and when I touch the module, I can feel that it's warm. **If I disconnect the GPIO2 pin,** the blue LED blinks once on power up, but according to the manual, it should blink twice. Manual also states that there should be a red LED, which apparently doesn't exist for this version.

**Raspberry**

1. I ran **raspi-config** and disabled "**Login shell over serial**"
2. I edited **/boot/config.txt** and added "**enable_uart=1**"
3. I edited **/boot/cmdline.txt** and it currently looks like this:

   dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
4. **dmesg | grep tty** returns:

   ```
   Kernel command line: 8250.nr_uarts=1 dma.dmachans=0x7f35 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=656 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=416 bcm2709.boardrev=0xa02082 bcm2709.serial=0x99a45a3 smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:9A:45:A3 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 bcm2709.uart_clock=48000000 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3dc00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x3f000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
   console [tty1] enabled
   3f215040.uart: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x3f215040 (irq = 59, base_baud = 31250000) is a 16550
   3f201000.uart: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x3f201000 (irq = 87, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
   systemd[1]: Starting system-getty.slice.
   systemd[1]: Created slice system-getty.slice.
   ```
5. Finally I tried to connect using the following commands:

   ```
   picocom /dev/ttyAMA0 -b 9600
   picocom /dev/ttyAMA0 -b 57600
   picocom /dev/ttyAMA0 -b 76800
   picocom /dev/ttyAMA0 -b 115200

   picocom /dev/ttyS0 -b 9600
   picocom /dev/ttyS0 -b 57600
   picocom /dev/ttyS0 -b 76800
   picocom /dev/ttyS0 -b 115200
   ```

But I can't type anything and when I restart the ESP8266, I see the blue LED blinking once (if GPIO2 is disconnected), but no data. Any ideas what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> VCC RaspberryPi 3V3

And there's your problem.

The 3V3 connection is rated for 50mA. The ESP8266 can draw over 200mA. Get a LDO regulator and connect it to the 5V connection instead.

Comment: I used a separate power source as you suggested. if I disconnected GPIO0 and GPIO2 then the module would blink a blue LED and show up as an access point, success! but, when I connect GPIO0 and GPIO2, the device doesn't blink the blue LED, but it's warm, so I guess it's turned on, but still can't write/read anything from/to serial. Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Raspberry PI 3 is slightly different that others PIs - the gpio pins has been swapped - thats why you had to disable Bluetooth. More on this topic here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/how-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3

Answer (score 1):

Strangely,after adding the following line to **/boot/config.txt** and rebooting, I'm actually started to receive garbage data:

```
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
```